# C# Adding a derived generic type to a Dictionary or List

Tags: c#, generics, interface

when I try the following in C#, I get an NPE. It's likely not how this should work:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Subscription<Event>>> subscriptionMap = new Dictionary<Type, List<Subscription<Event>>>();;

public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : Event {
  ...

  subscriptionMap[type].Add(new DefaultSubscription<T>(action) as Subscription<Event>);

  ...
}
```

Without the `as` I get compiler errors and with it, it just adds a null to the List. I should note that `Subscription` and `Event` are both interfaces. In Java I would simply say `<? extends Event>` or `<? extends Subscription<?>>` and this would work with no issues.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a `DefaultSubscription<T>` and how is it related to a `Subscription`?

Comment: It's implementing `Subscription<T : Event>`

Comment: Note that just because two types exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that doesn't mean that a generic parameterised by those types exhibits the *same* relationship. You're seeing a null precisely because the instance cannot be cast to the "base" type.

Comment: How am I supposed to create a generic list based off the base interface to store a combination of subscriptions in this case?

Comment: Even if I make `Subscription` concrete without a template I have the same issue with the `Action<T>` where I can't pass this into the `Subscription` because I cannot cast it to `Action<Event>` for what ever reason.

Comment: You really should include the code for your interfaces and classes and FYI the standard naming convention for interfaces is to start them with an upper case I.

Comment: Yeah coming from Java it's very different haha. I'll update that. I found out there really isn't an elegant way to accomplish this like I would in Java. So I guess I'll just mark the covariance link as the answer. Thanks for taking the time everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic delegates do not guarantee matching signatures.

What would happen if the `Subscribe<T>(Action<T>)` were to invoke the `Action<T>` with a concrete implementation?

```cs
Subscribe<ConcreteEvent>((ConcreteEvent e) => { });
...
private void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) 
    where T : Event
{
    action(new Event()); // Does not match method signature
    subscriptionMap[type].Add(new DefaultSubscription<T>(action) as Subscription<Event>);
}
```

This would result in a compiler error.

Whether the method signature expects a concrete subtype, or the `Event` base type, we can not say. The only thing we can say for certain, is that the method takes an argument which implements `Event`.

Therefore, we need to change the `Subscribe` method so the signature of `Action<T>` is known. Since the `Action<T>` delegate is [contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates), meaning that you can pass any subtype of `T` into the action, we can change the signature to `Action<Event>`.

```cs
public void Subscribe(Action<Event> action)
{
  subscriptionMap[type].Add(new DefaultSubscription<Event>(action));
}
```

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for pointing this out. I have changed my answer.